# Is there a term for the property of shapes that wraps back into itself?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology, noneuclidean-geometry

If you had a line segment and wanted it to wrap back into itself, you can join the two end and form a circle. You can do the same for a restricted plane into a sphere or torus.

Is there a name for the property of shapes joining back into itself? I was thinking perhaps "modular" from modular arithmetic but that has another meaning when referring to shapes.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [quotient spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)).

Comment: This will be very helpful. Thank you.